# autoconf libtool library linker path incorrect (need drive-letter) for ld.exe

Tags: linker, mingw, libtool

I use autoconf and when the target is mingw I was using the -mno-cygwin flag. This has been removed so I'm trying to using the mingw tool chain. The problem is the linker isn't finding my libraries

```
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link mingw32-g++  -g -Wall -pedantic -DNOMINMAX -D_REENTRANT -DWIN32 -I /usr/local/include/w32api  -L/usr/local/lib/w32api -o testRandom.exe testRandom.o -L../../../lib/Random -lRandom
libtool: link: mingw32-g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -DNOMINMAX -D_REENTRANT -DWIN32 -I /usr/local/include/w32api -o .libs/testRandom.exe testRandom.o  -L/usr/local/lib/w32api -L/home/Tam/src/3DS_Games/lib/Random -lRandom
D:\cygwin\opt\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lRandom
```

To link this from the command line using the mingw linker the `-L` path needs the drive letter i.e

```
mingw32-ld testRandom.o -LD:/home/Tam/src/3DS_Games/lib/Random -lRandom
```

works. The `-L` path is generated from the `makefile.am`'s which have

```
LDADD = -L$(top_builddir)/lib/Random -lRandom
```

However I can't find how to set `top_builddir` to a relative path or to start it with the drive letter (my autoconf skills are weak).

As a tempoary "solution" I have removed the use of libtool. I could hack a `$(DRIVE_LETTER)` infront of every -L option, but I'd like to find something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide it with unix-style paths

```
-L/cygdrive/D/home/Tam/src/3DS_Games/lib/Random
```

Comment: I actually moved on to using CMake so I am unable to retest with this solution, however I believe it is correct. It is also worth noting that the cygpath command is helpful for generating cygwin or window style paths.